# Gives data only through debugging selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a problem, I have a code

```
browser1.get("https://www.artstation.com/artwork/LeAN1P")


element = browser1.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='div.d-flex:nth-child(2) >  span:nth-child(2)')
for el in element:
    print(el.text)
```

I need to get the Views parameter, but everything ends with the successful execution of the code, despite the fact that if you run it through debug, then everything works

[Debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOfuG.png)

[Run console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPW1a.png)

if you integrate the code into another, then an error pops up, tell me how you can get the Views text data from this page
[launch in another finished project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faAei.png)

no ideas please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your elements are simply not loaded yet when script in run mode, as it's faster than debug. Before finding element wait for it to be located/visible etc
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: really thanks added parameter ```browser1.implicitly_wait()```
and everything worked